# Use separate divs for each set of inputs and labels and place id in hidden input

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, label

I have been told i need to do as the title says and use separate divs for each set of inputs and labels and place ID in a hidden input. could any one give me advice on how to do this please as i am just learning at the moment, my code for my labels and inputs are below:::

````
```
          <label for="editEmployeeFirstNameInput" class="form-label">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editEmployeeFirstNameInput" required>
          <label for="editEmployeeLastNameInput" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editEmployeeLastNameInput" required>
          <label for="editEmployeePositionInput" class="form-label">Position</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editEmployeePositionInput">
          <label for="editEmployeeEmailInput" class="form-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="editEmployeeEmailInput" required>
          <label for="editEmployeeDepartmentSelect" class="form-label">Department</label>
          <select id="editEmployeeDepartmentSelect" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
```
````

Comment: It helps if you give a clear overview of your intention. What do you want to achieve? Why do you feel you need a hidden input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
  <label for="editEmployeeFirstNameInput" class="form-label">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editEmployeeFirstNameInput" required>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="editEmployeeLastNameInput" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editEmployeeLastNameInput" required>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="editEmployeePositionInput" class="form-label">Position</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editEmployeePositionInput">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="editEmployeeEmailInput" class="form-label">Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="editEmployeeEmailInput" required>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="editEmployeeDepartmentSelect" class="form-label">Department</label>
  <select id="editEmployeeDepartmentSelect" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
```